# Can DispatchQueue be used to queue user inputs?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, queue, grand-central-dispatch

In my game, each time a user swipes in a particular direction something on screen animates. Since each animation takes about a second, if the user rapidly swipes on the screen I need a way to "log" all the functions the swipes would trigger and have them execute serially as they keep completing. I thought a Queue would be perfect for this and before implementing my own Queue I encountered `DispatchQueue`, `DispatchGroup`, and `DispatchWorkItem`. It got me wondering if there's a way to use `DispatchQueue` in conjunction with Groups and Work Items to queue up functions and have them execute one by one as they complete.

Please let me know if `DispatchQueue` can be used to queue up functions in this way.

I already know about the `.userInteractivity` global queue and am assuming something needs to be done over there; I just don't know what nor how.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use some kind of counter and increment that on each swipe and on each completion decrease by one

Comment: @SPatel what will I do when I change the counter? Do I do something using `DispatchQueue`?

Comment: You ca put a block on the `Dispatch.main` queue if you are doing things with the UI, or create a serial queue if you are not doing things with the UI.

Comment: @JeremyP I’m using 4 swipe gesture recognisers and each swipe moves a sprite in that direction. Each move takes about 2 seconds to complete and has animations. Does this count as “doing things with the UI?”

Comment: Yes. UIKit is not designed to be used by multiple threads. Anything on `Dispatch.main` is guaranteed to be executed by the main thread.

Comment: @JeremyP If I use the main queue, wont that block it? If I have to wait for each action to execute for each swipe I feel like that would cause unresponsiveness. Also, I’m completely new to all of this do you have any good resources for threads, queues, concurrency, sync, Async and all related concepts so I can read up on it

Comment: Your animations should be done in such a way as to not block the main thread. If you spend two seconds busy waiting on the main thread, your app will appear unresponsive no matter what.  With the official animation APIs, you normally just set the animation up in advance and tell it to go. Then UIKit/SpriteKit does the job of updating the graphics when needed.

Comment: The apple developer page on [concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) is a good place to start. Be aware that Swift recently added some [language features](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency/) for concurrency, but I don't have any experience in using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As appealing as it might seem, `DispatchQueue` is not an ideal tool for your use-case.

Dispatch queues are a very specific type of queue, a queue of code blocks to be executed in FIFO manner. Unfortunately, dispatch queues are not terribly elegant at managing dependencies between work items that are, themselves, asynchronous. And needless to say, your animations are asynchronous.

Admittedly, there are (kludgy) techniques to make this work with GCD, but it is not the most natural solution for your use-case. Operation queues handle dependencies between asynchronous tasks a bit better, but are unnecessarily complicated (one would need to create custom asynchronous `Operation` subclass with all the appropriate KVO notifications for `isExecuting`, `isFinished`, etc.).

One very simple solution, as you suggested, would be to have a your own FIFO queue of some model object that captures the user interaction:

- Have an `Array` for these user interactions;
- On user interaction, `append` values to that array;
- When starting an animation, `removeFirst` a value from that array; and
- When finishing an animation, recursively call itself, starting the next animation (if any).

E.g., below, I have a queue/array of `points` representing where the user tapped in the UI, and animate the position of a view in a FIFO manner. (To keep the code snippet simple, I created both the animated view and tap gesture recognizer in IB.)

```swift
import UIKit

class SimpleViewController: UIViewController {
    private var points: [CGPoint] = []
    private var isRunning = false

    @IBOutlet weak var animatedView: UIView!

    @IBAction func handleTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let point = gesture.location(in: view)
        points.append(point)
        moveNext()
    }

    func moveNext() {
        guard !points.isEmpty, !isRunning else {
            return
        }

        isRunning = true
        let point = points.removeFirst()

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) { [self] in
            animatedView.center = point
        } completion: { [self] isFinished in
            isRunning = false
            if isFinished { moveNext() }
        }
    }
}
```

The details here are not terribly relevant. The basic idea is that one can use an `Array` as a FIFO queue of user input.

---

If you have your heart set on using some framework object to manage your queue, you could consider the following, skipping dispatch/operation queue alternatives entirely.

- Instead, I would jump directly into Swift concurrency, with `async`-`await`, which gracefully handles dependencies between asynchronous tasks. See WWDC 2021 video [Meet async/await in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10132).
- Within Swift concurrency, I would use the “asynchronous sequence” pattern to manage a series of asynchronous tasks. See WWDC 2021 video [Meet AsyncSequence](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10058/).
- And to be more specific, I would use a particular type of `AsyncSequence`, namely a [`AsyncChannel`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Channel.md) (from the [Swift Async Algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms) library) to provide an asynchronous sequence in which your user input can easily add new items to that existing sequence.

```swift
import UIKit
import AsyncAlgorithms                            // https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms

class ChannelViewController: UIViewController {
    private let pointChannel = AsyncChannel<CGPoint>()
    private var channelTask: Task<Void, Never>?

    @IBOutlet weak var animatedView: UIView!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        startChannel()
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        stopChannel()
    }

    @IBAction func handleTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let point = gesture.location(in: view)
        Task {
            await pointChannel.send(point)
        }
    }

    func startChannel() {
        // in case we ever accidentally call this twice
        stopChannel()

        // create task …
        channelTask = Task {
            // … that iterates through `CGPoint` sent on the channel
            for await point in pointChannel {
                await move(to: point)
            }
        }
    }

    func stopChannel() {
        channelTask?.cancel()
        channelTask = nil
    }

    func move(to point: CGPoint) async {
        await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) { [self] in
                animatedView.center = point
            } completion: { _ in
                continuation.resume()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you are unfamiliar with [Swift concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency), you might want get familiar with that before delving into this `AsyncChannel` approach. But if you are looking for the most logical pattern for processing a sequence of asynchronous tasks, then `AsyncChannel` is worth consideration.